# Azure IoT Central App not listed in Azure Portal

Tags: azure-iot-central

I created an Azure IoT Central App by using the portal:
https://apps.azureiotcentral.com/

But this app is not being shown in the Azure portal. It is not in Azure IoT Central Apps "blade", where I was expecting to see the App created in the other portal:
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResource/resourceType/Microsoft.IoTCentral%2FIoTApps

Is this an expected behavior?

Thanks!

Cesar

Comment: It should be showing there (it does for me). Make sure you are using the same account in the Azure portal that you have used when creating the Central app. If this doesn't help, I'd suggest contacting support as this isn't really a developer question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback  Stefan Wick MSFT

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the App created in IoT Central App is not shown in Azure portal if the "**free** pricing plan is selected".

After selecting a different pricing plan, my Custom App appeared in Azure Portal!